# value toDF is not a member of Seq[(Int,String)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to execute the following code but getting this error:
`value toDF is not a member of Seq[(Int,String)]`.

I have the case class outside main and I have imported `implicits` too. But still I am getting this error. Can someone help me to resolve this ? I am using `Spark 2.11-2.1.0` and `Scala 2.11.8`

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql._
  import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering._
  import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
  import org.apache.spark._


  final case class Email(id: Int, text: String)

  object SampleKMeans {

     def main(args: Array[String]) = {

     val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SampleKMeans") 
                 .master("yarn")
                 .getOrCreate()

     import spark.implicits._

     val emails = Seq(
             "This is an email from...",
             "SPAM SPAM spam",
             "Hello, We'd like to offer you") 
             .zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toDF("id", "text").as[Email]

    }
  }
```

Comment: FYI.. just tried your code in the spark-shell and it works as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already have a `SparkSession` you can just `import` the `spark.implicits._` will work in your case

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SampleKMeans") 
             .master("local[*]")
             .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

Now `toDF` method works as expected.

If the error still exists, You need to check the version of `spark` and `scala` libraries that you are using.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have edited my question. I tried to execute your suggestion import spark.implicits._ but still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you running on `local` or `cluster` mode ? If you running on local you need to replace 'yarn' with `local[*]`

Comment: I am trying to run on cluster. Even before executing, I am getting this error in Eclipse.

Comment: yes, it is the exact error I am getting. Has it got something to do with the version ? Which version of spark and scala are you using ?

Comment: why do you need a sparkContext here ? You just need to import spark implicits and you are good to go.

Comment: Technically speaking importing `implicits` from `SQLContext` or `SparkSession` makes no difference. Both use the same code base from `SQLImplicits` and in fact `SparkSession` internally uses `SQLContext` instance to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks all. There was some problem with the versions of spark libraries. I fixed that by providing right versions of spark and scala libraries.

Comment: can you share exactly where you fixed this issue, i mean spark library version or in spark lib location